# sklearn ball tree - get centroid of a leaf

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How to get the centroid of each leaf from a sklearn ball tree when using nearest neighbors? 
It is easy to get all neighbors of a point, but I can't find a way to easily get the centroid of the terminal leaf wtih given radius.
It is possible to query every single point find the leaf and then manually  get the centroid.

```
import numpy as np
samples = np.array([[0., 0., 0.], [0., .5, 0.], [1., 1., .5]])
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
neigh = NearestNeighbors(radius=1.3, algorithm='ball_tree')
neigh.fit(samples) 

rng = neigh.radius_neighbors([[1., 1., .5]])
print(np.asarray(rng[0][0])) 
print(np.asarray(rng[1][0])) 

leaf_centroid = samples[rng[1][0]].mean(axis=0)
print(leaf_centroid)
```